# Typescript: unable to assign value to an enum mapped type in generic function

Tags: typescript, typescript-typings, typescript-generics

Code snippet here:

```
enum Foo {A, B, C}

interface FooData {
    [Foo.A]: null,
    [Foo.B]: {x: number, y: string},
    [Foo.C]: {x: boolean, z: number[]},
}

interface FooType<T extends Foo> {
    type: T;
    data: FooData[T];
}
type AllFoo = {[k in Foo]?: FooType<k>}

function setFooData<T extends Foo>(all: AllFoo, type: T, data: FooData[T]) {
    /// ERROR
    /// Type 'FooType<T>' is not assignable to type 'AllFoo[T]'.
    /// Type 'FooType<T>' is not assignable to type 'undefined'.
    all[type] = {type: type, data: data};
}

function setFooType<T extends Foo>(all: AllFoo, val: FooType<T>) {
    /// ERROR
    /// Same Error!
    all[val.type] = val;
}

const allFoo:AllFoo = {};
setFooData(allFoo, Foo.B, {x: 1, y: "2"});

console.log(`y is ${allFoo[Foo.B]?.data.y}`);
```

Wonder why Typescript wasn't able to infer the type here, or does the T need to be further narrowed?

Included [Playground link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ts=5.0.4#code/FAUwdgrgtgBAYgewTA3sGGYEEA07MBCemMAwngL7DACWYALiAE4BmAhgMYjxIAib9NqnwYA2ogQA6LAF0AXDEgAbJcUzikkgvNQAPBZCgAjZjhgBPBQGd6TOgHMKasRMmkdKfTCNIlINmBmAF4G0CZMojJOwFS0DMzsXDwIACrmAA4gADwpMCC6jGAAJlbJAHzCJPQZIAopANwiMEUCbAoS-IKiKTKNsdWZ2CoSMAC8qKIA1jB0yTIA-O1IaZlZk2WxLBBgHPQ0CGAwViD0Ha05eQXgJeUAFGwqCljDSGYDtTApZi2CSwidbG6MgAlJVMAB6SEwACiACVYQB5WFNSHgz41GAAcgkK2yKTKmJmpTACHoMDYVisNHsYDYRj8MHoyHeWOeSgkQMxkhRUNxWJxNRyBKJilJ5Mp1Np9O4TMZGMx2yKIBYdBARS5TQeSlE7xkY1Q7wU72+rQUPzYFD61C2Oz2ByOJwFq1y+UKNwkZXujyG7NeMAAbg8-rihaC0CRUTD4UieWiAMpsKDcaFMJgIJgAQk1KlEgaUkl1+rzVuAHAONnJLwQcjZI3GKEtwGOpz4rS9voQZlcRD0CgAjGZLDAAEQAJmHFGBjVL5YQfkkSgQ9luAANzCKACQoLUc7sLSTmyTmCgrqfAIA)

Expected to have no Typescript compile error. Have tried to use versions 4.6.4 and latest 5.0.4.

I know type assertion would work (add `val as AllFoo[T]`) but I'm trying to see if there's a solution without that.

Comment: Instead of `as` you can change  to `val: AllFoo[T]`

Comment: Yes, you should use `AllFoo[T]` instead of `FooType<T>`, since the former *distributes* over unions in `T` and the latter does not.  If `T` is `Foo` instead of just `Foo.A` or something, then they behave differently.  See both forms [in this playground link](https://tsplay.dev/WPgyEm).  Note that `AllFoo[T]` makes the error go away but is still technically unsound in the face of unions of `T`, but I don't know if you care much (since the question isn't about that).  Anyway, does that fully address the question? If so I'll write up an answer post; if not, what am I missing?

Comment: Thanks for reply! I have rephrased the question/code a little bit to match better with the real life scenario. Basically I'm providing the setFoo... functions as convenience, and at some point it needs to convert `FoodType<T>` to `AllFoo[T]`. I could directly set the `all[T] = AllFoo[T];` But it kind of defeats the purpose.

Comment: I don't understand what you mean by defeating the purpose.  I would refactor your new code to [this version](https://tsplay.dev/WG8ZMw) if you want the compiler to verify type safety, as described in [ms/TS#47109](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/pull/47109).  If you don't distribute over unions then you are writing the wrong thing.  I'm happy to write this up as an answer if it works for you. Let me know how to proceed.

Comment: Ah I see. Yeah this is basically I was looking for. I don't fully understand how the "distribution" rule works here yet. But seems like reversing the `type AllFoo = {[k in Foo]?: FooType<k>}` to `type FooType<K extends Foo> = RequiredAllFoo[K]` somehow does the trick. Would accept this answer if you write it up. Thanks a lot!

Comment: OK. I modified my code snippet a little bit accordingly and seems like what it matters is the AllFoo must be declared as generic, guess that's how T can be distributed [playground](https://tsplay.dev/WYe6dW)

Comment: I will write up an answer explaining as soon as I get back to my real computer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The minimum change you need to make to prevent the error is to make `AllFoo` [generic](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/generics.html) in the set of keys it has, and then make your `setFoo∗` accept an `all` of type `AllFoo<T>` instead of just `AllFoo` (although every `AllFoo` should also be an `AllFoo<T>` for any `T extends Foo`, and therefore technically it shouldn't be needed):

```
type AllFoo<K extends Foo = Foo> = { [P in K]?: FooType<P> }

function setFooData<T extends Foo>(all: AllFoo<T>, type: T, data: FooData[T]) {
    all[type] = { type: type, data: data }; // okay
}

function setFooType<T extends Foo>(all: AllFoo<T>, val: FooType<T>) {
    all[val.type] = val; // okay
}
```

This approach is essentially as described in [microsoft/TypeScript#47109](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/pull/47109), which is the recommended way to deal with these sort of correlations.

---

Note though that your `FooType<T>` type isn't great, though.  This:

```
interface FooType<T extends Foo> {
    type: T;
    data: FooData[T];
}
```

does the wrong thing when `T` is a [union type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#union-types) like `Foo` itself:

```
type FooTypeFoo = FooType<Foo>;
/* type FooTypeFoo = {
   type: Foo;
   data: 
     { x: number; y: string; } | 
     { x: boolean; z: number[]; } | 
     null;
} 
*/

const ftf: FooTypeFoo // no compiler error,
    = { type: Foo.B, data: null }; // but you DON'T want to accept this
```

You want the compiler to *distribute* the `FooType<T>` operation over unions in `T`, so that `FooType<Foo>` would be

```
type FooTypeFoo = FooType<Foo>;
/* type FooTypeFoo = 
  { type: Foo.A; data: null; } | 
  { type: Foo.B; data: { x: number; y: string; }; } | 
  { type: Foo.C; data: { x: boolean; z: number[]; };
} */

const ftf: FooTypeFoo // error!
    = { type: Foo.B, data: null };
```

This means ideally `FooType` should be a *distributive object type* (where you [index into](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/indexed-access-types.html) a [mapped type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/mapped-types.html) as described in microsoft/TypeScript#47109:

```
type FooType<T extends Foo> = { [P in T]: {
    type: P;
    data: FooData[P];
} }[T]
```

That behaves as desired.

Generally speaking the compiler allows some unsoundness around generic indexed accesses so you should be careful.  The refactoring of `FooType` now prevents bad calls to `setFooType()`, but you can still do bad things with `setFooData()` if `T` is a union type.  These can be patched up as well but I won't digress further going into it, especially if it's unlikely you'll actually see people using the code incorrectly.  I'll just note that it would be nice if we could prevent unions from happening at all (since you almost certainly don't want `T` to be a union), so hopefully one day something like [microsoft/TypeScript#27808](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/27808) will be implemented.

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ts=5.0.4#code/FAUwdgrgtgBAYgewTA3sGGYEEA07MBCemMAwngL7DACWYALiAE4BmAhgMYjxIAib9NqnwYA2ogQA6LAF0AXDEgAbJcUzikkgvNQwAHgshQARsxwwAngoDO9JnQDmMCmrETJpHSn0LjSJSBsYOYAXobQpkyiMs6U1MBgbFAg1gAOnNwA8koAJgBqzNY0CGDCIjD0FqncEgAqVSAAPLUwIHqMYDnWPAgAfDAAvMIkJJXVCrUA3OUkOQJsChL8gqK1MtMkVKMNPfXVEoO7DY0SvRuYAPQAVBU7dQ0HQ2jb4z3nGHOCCjO6BooRzEmlhsdkcQIoMAAPjAft4-n4EAEgkCwv8TMxouCoTCRv8VO9nDArhdyhwSrYYCx6CxFkg9iAJD8ME9bq93EQYJ8FnilM4gRcLjAEABrNgWczGCD0SwICCckoAcmlAHcgtL6MhOFxUuqABY0azAKjAMY1OnHFptDpdHr9FmiAAKMDoMDWCmemFNCgdBK5tIQyzYjvWRucqxk1FNR32SEO92qJyQZ2A11ZZoQ9MeON0Xp60iBfp5WOh+G8ufZBfm7p8aMiQKsMFs9jADnBxezZYa-o8la+v18-kCYBR4XRUXWfNDxMjOywKgkjQA0q12uAbVnTodvI7naVFzIAPz++mNB39Y0sCBgDj0YqlawgehLebNFfW7qnAAUbBUCjnSgXWpenMXNanMQtnxWNYAEphkwH8lFEU0YhZXNTXAqtOXmScLyvG870bR94yaS1V06D8k2-X9sHnJBmmAmAADcf2PC1elgj0MAQ0RmKUSRkMOXjpmNMkwApBCJD-WjkCeChpgfJ8+HmKiAKQcx2XMOEFAARnMBsACIACZ9OcaDpmAUTrEREBJCUBAHE-AADCxnW6AASFAJKQDQpG0A9JC5SQLAoRyzOAIA)